# Can I create filter drivers in linux like the ones in Windows?

Tags: windows, linux-kernel, driver

In the Windows operating system,  I can create filter drivers for keyboards, mouses and other devices. There is the concept of the "device stack". Is there anything similar on linux? If so, is there any article or tutorial about filter drivers in linux?

Comment: I can't think of anything similar in Linux. In AT&T Unix, System V had a thing called "STREAMS" (written in ALL CAPS like that) which was similar. It was used for implementing network stacks and TTY line disciplines.